# Why isn't Composer able to find/install my package for Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, github, composer-php, laravel-5, packagist

I am using Laravel 5.2.23 and am unable to pull in my new package, [bsapaka/metattribute](http://packagist.org/packages/bsapaka/metattribute). I get the exception:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>       Could not find package bsapaka/metattribute at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability

Composer seems to have it:

Running `composer show bsapaka/metattribute` returns:

```
name     : bsapaka/metattribute
descrip. : classes for Laravel attributes
keywords : attribute, attributes, properties, alias, meta attribute
versions : dev-master
type     : library
(more)
```

So I am wondering if I am missing something in the `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "bsapaka/metattribute",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "classes for Laravel attributes",
    "keywords": [
        "attribute",
        "attributes",
        "properties",
        "meta attribute",
        "alias"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/bsapaka/metattribute",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "illuminate/support": "~5.1",
        "php" : "~5.5|~7.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "bsapaka\\metattribute\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

I have done a good bit of docs reading, troubleshooting, adding in `mininum-stability`, checking the versioning, comparing against other packages, validating JSON, looking for the tidbits I missed etc, and at this point I could really use some guidance on where I might be going wrong. Thanks for reading, and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any version tag defined in your `master` branch on GitHub.

If there is no version tag then Composer doesn't know which version is the stable one. So if you have `"minimum-stability": "stable"` in the project which is requiring your self made package it can't find any stable version.

Create a new tag (e.g. 1.0.0) in your master branch on GitHub to declare the latest commit as stable or use the `dev-master` version and `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in the project which is requiring your self made package.